# Tkinter: pack's anchor option is not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I've two file for my app, and in my second one `page_one.py` I can't use properly the anchor method. The label 'left' and 'right' are always positioned in the middle of the screen and not on the side

```
# main.py
import tkinter as tk
from page_one import PageOne

class Main(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

    self.page_one = PageOne(self)
    self.page_one.pack(expand='True')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  root = tk.Tk()
  main = Main(root)
  root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
  main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
  root.mainloop()
```

```
# page_one.py
import tkinter as tk

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)  
                                                            
        self.one_label = tk.Label(self, text='LEFT')
        self.one_label.pack(padx=(20,0), side='left', anchor='w')  

        self.two_label = tk.Label(self, text='RIGHT')
        self.two_label.pack(padx=(0,20), side='right', anchor='e') 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    PageOne(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

How can I make the  `anchor` option works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your `PageOne` frame doesn't fill `Main`. Add `fill="both"` to its `pack` method as well:

```
import tkinter as tk

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)  
                                                            
        self.one_label = tk.Label(self, text='LEFT')
        self.one_label.pack(padx=(20,0), side='left', anchor='w')  

        self.two_label = tk.Label(self, text='RIGHT')
        self.two_label.pack(padx=(0,20), side='right', anchor='e') 
 

class Main(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

    self.page_one = PageOne(self)
    self.page_one.pack(expand='True', fill="both")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  root = tk.Tk()
  main = Main(root)
  #root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
  root.geometry("1280x720")
  main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
  root.mainloop()
```

Note that you can use `super()` in your `init` functions (without `self` as argument)

Comment: Thank you! That worked very well. Just a question if you have time to to respond me: what is super() and why is better then using self as argument? Once again, thanks!

Comment: `super()` refers to the class you're inheriting from. Basically saving you from repeating yourself here. In other situations it can have more advantages, see [here](https://realpython.com/python-super/) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `fill="both"` when packing the `PageOne` frame for it to expand completely in the x and y axis. Update your `main.py` accordingly.

```
# main.py
import tkinter as tk
from page_one import PageOne

class Main(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

    self.page_one = PageOne(self)
    self.page_one.pack(fill="both", expand='True')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  root = tk.Tk()
  main = Main(root)
  root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
  main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
  root.mainloop()
```